# How does gnu Make handle the dependencies?

Tags: makefile

we currently generate a dependency file for every .o. But when do an incremental build, Make reads from the dependency file for dependencies for each .o. Is Make checking the time stamp of these dependent files and compare it with the .o? If so, is it possible to cache the status of dependencies to avoid too much I/O hit because of duplicated status checks for each object file?

```
for example, 
a.o: h1.h h2.h
    gcc...
b.o: h1.h h2.h
    gcc...
```

If we cache the status of h1.h and h2.h when it builds a.o, do we save two checks when build b.o?

I am not familiar with the make system, but is currently looking for ways to improve its performance on a large legacy C project.

Comment: is this really a problem? How many dependencies are you tracking? How long does it take to build now?

Comment: yes, file I/O is a problem, it is slow. Our source code got to 2.5G in size, and for a typical C file, we have about 800 dependencies. It usually takes 3-4 hours to build. But of course, this is not the only problem we have, and certainly not the biggest one,  we just want to experiment with different options.

Comment: If it's always the same .h files, have you tried `a.o, b.o: h1.h h2.h` already?

Comment: It is not always the same .h files. that's just an example to illustrate the question I have.

Comment: ElectricMake and ElectricInsight together make performance analysis of your build process easy. Before you spend too much time staring at strace logs, you should give it a try and see if it can help you focus your efforts on the biggest, lowest-hanging fruit.  http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator-dev.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strace` for that purpose:

```
strace -e trace=stat make --touch
```

Output of the first run (full build):

```
...
stat("a.o", 0x7fff70c35f00)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("h1.h", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("h2.h", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
touch a.o
stat("b.o", 0x7fff70c35f00)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
touch b.o
```

And the second run (incremental build):

```
...
stat("a.o", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("h1.h", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("h2.h", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("b.o", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

As you can see, GNU Make caches timestamps avoiding unnecessary `stat` syscalls. However, I guess, things are not so good in case of using recursive make.

Comment: Thanks, too bad, we have recursive make, but at least we now know GNU Make does cache.